# Why does making huge number of requests to AWS ELB result in unknown host error?

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, amazon-elb

I am running some perf tests against my API.

Roughly:

- 100k requests in one minute
- ~10k ALB active connection count
- ~13k ALB new connection count

The ELB sits in front of 4 m4.large instances, I'm seeing almost no CPU usage. The requests I make eventually starts throwing "Failed to open a socket" and eventually 'UnknownHostException'. It's as if my ELB decided to just rejects these requests and started hiding itself...

I thought ELB don't really have a limit? Even if it did, I would say my numbers are pretty low?

Comment: Are you trying to open/send all requests from one single machine ?

Comment: With UnknownHostException - the are could be problem on your(client) side

Comment: on my own machine. i have rules set up so the requests goes out, at every second number of concurrent request is increase by 50, capped at 5k.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem that you are experiencing is that you are overloading the ELB. The solution is called "Pre-Warming". This means that it takes a period of time for the ELB to grow to handle a sudden increase in traffic. You need to contact AWS Support to solve this by making a request to pre-warm your ELB.

A better solution is to switch to the newer NLB (Network Load Balancer) which does not need pre-warming.

Comment: It's difficult if not impossible to justify the assertion that "unknown host" is related to ELB capacity.  There is no logical reason for that specific error in that context... not to mention that we appear to be dealing with < 65K concurrent connections.

Comment: Michael, This is a pretty common issue when customers use performance testers against an ELB. Amazon has a document that specifically mentions how to use testers. https://aws.amazon.com/articles/1636185810492479 . The unknown here is how the client testing software behaves when the ELB is overloaded, e.g. as it takes longer and longer to complete a connection, is the client running out of sockets? A sudden increase of 23,000 users in less than 5 minutes is not support by the Classic load balancer. Do not increase traffic more then 50% every five minutes. The ALB has the same recommendation.

Comment: Michael, ran of of space on the last comment. As the TCP/IP stack runs out of available connection slots, it wont be able to resolve host names either.

Comment: Agreed about the TCP stack, but that all points to a problem with the client side of the test scenario.  An ELB/ALB doesn't do any kind of name resolution, it's all based on IP addresses.  Granted, too, with an overly-aggressive ramp-up, you're quite right that balancer scaling *can* be an issue... it just doesn't sound like the issue here.  Something is flawed with the test.

Comment: For this case, I would repeat the test waiting about five minutes after the last failure as the ELB will have auto scaled up. If it takes longer to get to failure (or no failure at all) then this will point to the ELB pre warm issue. If it starts to fail in a similar way then this will point to the client having the issue. Note: One issue that we have not thought of - has the customer configured the ELB in multiple AZs so that there is room to scale up?

Comment: Suggestion, Add an NLB configured similarly to the same instances (you can have more than one load balancer configured with the same EC2 instances). Then repeat the test against the NLB. If you see very different results, then the ELB is the issue. If you see the same issue, then you have a client or network issue.

Comment: I'll check out this NLB tomorrow. Thanks for the advise!